# JQuery toggle stops working after I make a server-side asp.net call?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, webforms, updatepanel

I have a div called address which as a textarea.  When I click a hyperlink, it toggles the div up and down. After clicking a an asp.net button the div collapses which is fine, but I noticed the url turns from www.abc.com/edit.aspx?Id=2 to www.abc.com/edit.aspx?Id2=2# and now the toggle does not work.

Here is the script:

$(document).ready(function () {

```
    $('#myAddress').click(function () {
        ShowHideAddressBox();
    });
    $('#arrowIndicator').click(function () {
        ShowHideAddressBox();
    });
});
function ShowHideAddressBox() {
    var str = $("#myAddress").text();
    if (str == "Hide") {
        $("#myAddress").html("Click here");
        $("#arrowIndicator").attr("src", "/Shared/Images/misc/arrow_state_grey_expanded.png");
    }
    else {
        $("#myAddress").html("Hide");
        $("#arrowIndicator").attr("src", "/Shared/Images/misc/arrow_state_grey_collapsed.png");
    }

    $('#checkAddress').toggle('normal');
}
```

The server-side button click just sets some values in a couple textboxes.

In my master page, I have the following line as well:

```
<asp:ScriptReference Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
            Name="MicrosoftAjax.js" Path="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/3.5/MicrosoftAjax.js" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're seeing is because the elements are being replaced, and they no longer have the handlers, you should replace this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myAddress').click(function () {
        ShowHideAddressBox();
    });
    $('#arrowIndicator').click(function () {
        ShowHideAddressBox();
    });
});
```

With a [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) handler like this:

```
$(function () { //shortcut for $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#myAddress, #arrowIndicator').live('click', ShowHideAddressBox);
});
```

Comment: I will implement this and let you know but if I understand you correctly, you are saying that on page load, the function ShowHideAddressBox is attached to the link, but after the toggle, ShowHideAddress is no longer attached?  Is that correct and is it because of showing and hiding the div or something else.  I'm a little confused about replacing the elements part because I don't think I am replacing and element, I am just hiding and showing one that is already there.  I probably confused myself more.  I am gonna try your solution now and let you know.

Comment: @Xaisoft - It's the postback to the server (the asp button click you describe) that brings *new* elements, without the `click` handlers you attached to the original.

Comment: That worked great.  I kind of understand, but I am still a little confused.  After clicking the asp.net button, the ShowHideAddressBox function is no longer attached to the link and image, so live will reattach them.  The part that is confusing is when you say brings new elements.  All the elements are already on the page, the only thing the server click does is populate some textboxes with values, but the textboxes are there already.  Sorry if I am being a pain.

Comment: @Xaisoft - They are already there, but when you click the button, anything inside that `<UpdatePanel>` gets replaced...even if it *looks* the same, they're new elements.  So `.live()` doesn't "re-attach" them, it works differently...but it has the same effect, it works on elements regardless of when they were added.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent the default action of the anchor (which is to follow the href). If you have got your anchor href set to '#' and do not use this it will append the # to the url in the address bar.

```
$('#arrowIndicator').click(function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        ShowHideAddressBox();
});
```

Comment: This won't actually solve the issue, if the read carefully it stops working because of a partial page postback (AJAX request replacing elements) :)

Comment: Nick is correct, I put ev.preventDefault() and now the div doesn't toggle at all.

Comment: @Nick Craver - oh yeah, grim updatepanels, long time since I have used them thankfully

Comment: @Xaisoft sorry to mislead you, but there is black magic involved!!

Comment: It is ok redsquare, I appreciate the help.  I thought it had something to do with preventDefault or preventPropagtion stuff as well.  All this stuff is very annoying to me, lol.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
      //Code that runs after a post back with an update panel has occurred.  
    } 
      //Code on page load.
});
```

The code outside of the function EndRequestHandler would be the same as inside of it.

I used update panels when I was new to asp.net and programming in general. I quickly learned to use jQuery ajax, which is way a better solution than update panels. I suggest you check it out.